# Does the pipe opperator turn a data frame into a tibble? If so, how can I prevent it?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm playin around with `chisq_test()` using the `gss_cat` dataset (from `forcats`, from `tidyverse`). First, I created the contingency table:

```
> gss_cat %>%
+     group_by(race, partyid) %>%
+     summarise(Freq = n()) %>%
+     pivot_wider(names_from = race, values_from = Freq) %>%
+     drop_na() %>%
+     column_to_rownames("partyid")
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'race' (override with `.groups` argument)
                   Other Black White
No answer             25    36    93
Other party           22    22   349
Strong republican     81    56  2177
Not str republican   156    88  2788
Ind,near rep         118    92  1581
Independent          612   491  3016
Ind,near dem         285   352  1862
Not str democrat     437   746  2507
Strong democrat      223  1246  2021
```

Then, I applied the test and got the residulas (for which I'm looking for):

```
gss_cat %>%
  group_by(race, partyid) %>%
  summarise(Freq = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = race, values_from = Freq) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  column_to_rownames("partyid") %>%
  chisq.test(.) %>%
  `[[`("residuals")
```

gives

```
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'race' (override with `.groups` argument)
                       Other       Black      White
No answer           2.923648   2.8649510  -2.262282
Other party        -2.311635  -4.6581430   2.834128
Strong republican  -8.950509 -15.3086303   9.782022
Not str republican -7.246500 -16.8275514   9.856563
Ind,near rep       -3.546661 -10.4554526   5.793770
Independent        12.196368  -4.4484394  -2.272619
Ind,near dem        3.783087  -0.6287861  -1.033036
Not str democrat    5.478600   8.9946078  -5.823392
Strong democrat    -5.339841  32.7172447 -12.447571
```

Now, I'd like to turn `partyid` back into a column. Then I tried using `rownames_to_column()`, but get an error message:

```
> gss_cat %>%
+   group_by(race, partyid) %>%
+   summarise(Freq = n()) %>%
+   pivot_wider(names_from = race, values_from = Freq) %>%
+   drop_na() %>%
+   column_to_rownames("partyid") %>%
+   chisq.test(.) %>%
+   `[[`("residuals") %>%
+   rownames_to_column("partyid")
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'race' (override with `.groups` argument)
Error in rownames_to_column(., "partyid") : is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm don't use this programming style but I'm pretty sure that the pipe operator doesn't change any classes. Your issue is with (at least) one of the 8 functions you are calling. E.g., `group_by` is documented to return something called a "grouped_df".

Comment: The error happened after I add the line `rownames_to_column("partyid")`. That's why I believe the problem is either in the line before (`[["residuals"`), in the pipe opperator or `rownames_to_column()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to convert the object to `data.frame` before you can use `renames_to_column`:

```
gss_cat %>%
  group_by(race, partyid) %>%
  summarise(Freq = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = race, values_from = Freq) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  column_to_rownames("partyid") %>%
  chisq.test(.) %>%
  `[[`("residuals") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("partyid")
#              partyid     Other       Black      White
# 1          No answer  2.923648   2.8649510  -2.262282
# 2        Other party -2.311635  -4.6581430   2.834128
# 3  Strong republican -8.950509 -15.3086303   9.782022
# 4 Not str republican -7.246500 -16.8275514   9.856563
# 5       Ind,near rep -3.546661 -10.4554526   5.793770
# 6        Independent 12.196368  -4.4484394  -2.272619
# 7       Ind,near dem  3.783087  -0.6287861  -1.033036
# 8   Not str democrat  5.478600   8.9946078  -5.823392
# 9    Strong democrat -5.339841  32.7172447 -12.447571
```